# How to choose $u_i$'s for Chvatal-Gomory cutting plane?

Tags: linear-programming

Trying to understand the example of Chvatal-Gomory cutting planes ([Lee](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521010128) p. 153), they say:

> $\max 2x_1 + x_2 $ 
>   subject to: 
>   $7x_1 + x_2 \leq 28$ 
>   $-x_1 +3x_2 \leq 7$ 
>  
>   $-8x_1 -9x_2 \leq -32 $
>  
>   $x_1, x_2 \geq 0$ 
>  
>   $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$
>
> The choice of $u_1=0$, $u_2=1/3$, $u_3=1/3$ yields the cutting plane $-3x_1 - 2x_2 \leq -9$. The choice of $u_1 = 1/21$, $u_2=7/22$, $u_3=0$ yields the cutting plane $x_2\leq 3$.

But have no idea how they made that "choice" for the u's! Is it just a guess?

Any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is just a guess. The topic of "how" to choose them is covered later in the book, like in the next chapter.